# Connecting to SQL Server from Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL Server and I try to connect from PHP to my SQL Server; I've already extracted SQL Server extra into php/ext:

[image]

And after that I try to put extension into php.ini

[image]

but I always get this error:

[image]

How can I solve this? The driver never been installed then

Comment: **Just as a note**: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: in your php.ini, remove the semi-colon from the front of extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts